# How to disable Firebase Phone Auth reCAPTCHA? (Web/React)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm building a React + Firebase app and using Firebase's PhoneAuthProvider for authentication.

During a development, there's a lot of logging in and out to test auth flow, private routes, redirects on login etc.

Every time I need to log in, I'm being shown a reCAPTCHA challenge. This is super annoying.

And because I'm making so many login requests in a short time frame from the same IP, **I'm being shown several (sometimes 10!) reCAPTCHA challenges**. Probably because Google thinks this is suspicious behaviour.

How do I disable reCAPTCHA during development?

If this is not possible, what is a possible workaround for this?

It is simply not practical to continue this way?

Here's my firebaseui config:

```
const uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/home',
    signInOptions: [{
        provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        recaptchaParameters: {
            type: 'image',
            size: 'invisible',
            badge: 'bottomleft'
        },
        defaultCountry: 'IN'
    }],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Firebase Authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#set-up-the-recaptcha-verifier):

> Firebase uses reCAPTCHA to prevent abuse, such as by ensuring that the phone number verification request comes from one of your app's allowed domains.

So you won't be able to just disable it, as that would defeat its purpose.

But during development you can do most of your [testing with whitelisted phone numbers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers). This should allow you to bypass most of the problems you're hitting.

---

As @bojeil commented, you can also set the [`appVerificationDisabledForTesting` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.AuthSettings.html#appverificationdisabledfortesting) to true after doing the above, to completely disable the recaptcha during testing.

Comment: I've used testing phone numbers but still get shown the reCAPTCHA challenge sometimes. :/ 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey @akshaykay, if you need this for development, file a feature request to completely disable reCAPTCHA in firebaseui-web when `appVerificationDisabledForTesting` is set to `true`.